# I wanna have a <apex:selectList that automatically fetches select options from an object's field

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, selectlist, dynamic-binding

How to achieve a functionality where i have a

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectList id="countries" value="{!Location__c.Country__c}"
            size="1" required="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!countries}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class DynamicPicklistController
{
    public List<SelectOption> getCountries()
    {
      List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
      Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =
      Location__c.Country__c.getDescribe();
      List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

       for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
       {
          options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
       }       
       return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: if Country__c is a picklist field the you can simply use `<apex:inputField value="{!Location__c.Country__c}" />`. This will generate picklist for you

Comment: what if i add values to that picklist,should those changes be visible?

Comment: if you add values to the picklist and when you open the VF page and view this picklist. It will contain all the picklist value including those you have added recently

Answer (score 2):

if `Country__c` is a picklist field the you can simply use

`<apex:inputField value="{!Location__c.Country__c}" />`

This will generate picklist for you